# c++ compilation on class vector

Tags: c++, compilation

How to solve the following compilation problem (in dev c++)?

> [Error] 'class std::vector' has no member named 'shrink_to_fit'

[image]

Comment: All questions here should have all relevant information ***in the question itself as plain text***. Links can stop working at any time making questions meaningless. Code, data, or errors shown as images cannot be copy/pasted; or edited or compiled for further research and investigation. Can you [edit] this question, removing and replacing all links and images with all relevant information as plain text? All code ***must meet all requirements for a [mre]***. You'll find many other questions here, with a [mre], in plain text. Please use them as an example for how your question should look.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: [shrink_to_fit was added in c++11](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/shrink_to_fit). perhaps you are compiling with an older version.

Comment: Why are you using Dev C++?  It's long past its sell by date.

Comment: the problem is that I may have to install a library so that the compilation can pass and display the results
so I don't know which compilers or library to install
i have windows 10 and i work in dev c++

Comment: Dariush, so what do i need to install??

Comment: Check that your compiler (or compiler version) supports C++11 or later, since `std::vector::shrink_to_fit()` was introduced in C++11.    If your compiler and library does not support C++11 or later, then update your compiler and library.    If your compiler and library version DOES support C++, read the documentation - it is not exactly unusual that C++11 (or later) support is disabled by default, so you need to use compiler specific switches (e.g. command line options) to enable it.

Comment: what commands can i use to solve the problem?

Comment: @PaulSanders Unfortunately, many colleges still teach you to use Dev C++, in fact, it is a **requirement**. I don't know what is their reasoning behind this *(and `using namespace std;`)*, but it makes every new college-educated programmer unable to keep up-to-date with new technologies.

Comment: @thedemons OK, but the OP should tell us that if it applies to him.

Answer (score 1):

[shrink_to_fit was added in c++11](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/shrink_to_fit). perhaps you are compiling with an older version.
from your screenshot, it seems you are using dev. (BTW why don't you use a newer program for development?). to adjust your compiler with the latest C++ standard available in Dev (which at the moment of typing this answer is C++ 11, three generations behind the latest C++ 23!) you have to:

1. under "Tools", choose "Compiler Options"
   [image]
2. the select compiler that you wish to configure. I'm choosing the "TDM-GCC 4.9.2 64-bit Release".
   [image]
3. under "Settings", choose "Code Generation". then, click on the "Language standard (-std)". (this is equivalent to the -std argument which is passed to compilers to compile under the desired language standard). click on the entry to select the language standard. in this case, I'm choosing ISO C++ 11.
   [image]
4. click OK to save your changes.
   [image]
5. after making sure the selected compiler matches the one that we applied those settings, hit the compile and run button and your program shall be compiled with your new configuration :D
   [image]

Comment: Dariush,I did that the problem still exists......

Comment: @otman I'm sorry to hear that. but are you sure you have done them as instructed? I have just installed Dev on my system to check that out. it works for me (as it can be seen on my last screenshot). also, I have updated my answer and re-instructed the steps to resolve the problem, step-by-step with screenshots and descriptions.